# MYSQL - SUM of a column based on common value in other column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm stuck on crafting a MySQL query to solve a problem. I'm trying to iterate through a list of "sales" where I'm trying to sort the Customer IDs listed by their total accumulated spend.

```
|Customer ID| Purchase price|
10          |1000
10          |1010
20          |2111
42          |9954
10          |9871
42          |6121
```

How would I iterate through the table where I sum up purchase price where the customer ID is the same?

Expecting a result like:

```
Customer ID|Purchase Total
10          |11881
20          |2111
42          |16075
```

I got to: select Customer ID, sum(PurchasePrice) as PurchaseTotal from sales where CustomerID=(select distinct(CustomerID) from sales) order by PurchaseTotal asc;
But it's not working because it doesn't iterate through the CustomerIDs, it just wants the single result value...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` your customer id:

```
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(PurchasePrice) AS PurchaseTotal
FROM sales
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Comment: That was brilliant. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Select CustomerID, sum(PurchasePrice) as PurchaseTotal FROM sales GROUP BY CustomerID ORDER BY PurchaseTotal ASC;

Answer (score 1):

Just by having a little Google search, I managed to find a page doing exactly what you're doing (I think). I have tailored the query below to fit your circumstance.

```
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(PurchasePrice) AS PurchaseTotal
FROM sales
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY PurchaseTotal ASC
```

[Link to Page with Tutorial on SQL Groups](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm)